# Where can I find good tutorials and guides on wxPython and wxGlade?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxglade

Just out of curiosity, aside from their respective sites, have any of you guys found a better resource for figuring out wxPython/wxGlade?

I figured I'd ask while I'm chewing on something else, I plan on using those tools to create a GUI for the project I've started.

Answer (score 2):

wxGlade: http://wiki.wxpython.org/WxGladeTutorial

A video tutorial for wxGlade: http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=7850030&fromSeriesID=785

wxPython in general: http://www.wxpython.org/tutorial.php

Another wxPython tutorial: http://www.zetcode.com/wxpython/

It is also a good idea to study the code samples in wxPython's Demo application (installed with its documentation package) for the widgets you want to use.

**Warning:** There're bugs in wxPython have left unfixed for a long time. For example the wxAuiNotebook and such complex widgets have such bugs and deficiencies.

Comment: Sorry for listing the "respective sites" as well. They are for later reference for those finding this answer useful later.

Answer (score 0):

For wxpython, apart from the wxpython.org site of course, you might want to look at [this](http://www.zetcode.com/wxpython/) (slightly dated) tutorial and [these](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/series?name=PythonWxPythonBeginnersSeries) five videos. For wxglade, again apart from the specific sites, there's a video tutorial [here](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=7850030&fromSeriesID=785) (though I haven't seen it, and I know little about wxglade so I'm not sure how helpful my opinion would be here;-).